# MYSQL Should I use inner join to extract data on Max Date

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A

```
ID  id_update_dt
100067842   3/27/21
100100227   3/27/21
100319616   3/25/21
100344419   3/27/21
100464912   3/27/21
100570028   3/25/21
100608364   3/27/21
100624076   3/25/21
100643085   3/27/21
100645028   3/27/21][1]
```

Table B

```
ID  id_update_dt
100067842   3/25/21
100100227   3/25/21
100319616   3/25/21
100344419   3/25/21
100464912   3/25/21
100570028   3/25/21
100608364   3/25/21
100624076   3/25/21
100643085   3/25/21
100645028   3/25/21
```

Data in above tables having a unique id with date. I would like to extract only id's  from table A
with a.date > b date om matching id

I want to extract this data

```
100067842 3/27/21
100100227 3/27/21
100344419 3/27/21
100464912 3/27/21
100643085 3/27/21
100645028 3/27/21
```

I tried this but did not work.

```
select
A.subscription_nbr A.date
from
A join B
  on A.subscription_nbr = B.subscription_nbr
and A.dw_update_dt > B.dw_update_dt
```

Can some body help. I am not that good in SQL.

Thanks for the help in Advance

Comment: Please refer the link for the sample tables

Comment: When you say "this did not work", what do you mean exactly?  Do you receive an error message?  (If so, you should post the details).  Or do you mean that it returns no rows?  (If that's what you mean, then I'm not surprised - your sample data doesn't show any "a" table rows that have a date greater than the corresponding "b" table data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.id = a.id and
                        b.id_update_dt >= a.id_update_dt
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work. You just missed the comma between two columns in select list.

```
select
A.ID, A.id_update_dt
from
A inner join B
  on A.ID = B.ID
and A.id_update_dt> B.id_update_dt
```

Schema:

```
 create table A (ID int, id_update_dt date);

 insert into A values(100067842   ,'2021-3-27');
 insert into A values(100100227   ,'2021-3-27');
 insert into A values(100319616   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into A values(100344419   ,'2021-3-27');
 insert into A values(100464912   ,'2021-3-27');
 insert into A values(100570028   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into A values(100608364   ,'2021-3-27');
 insert into A values(100624076   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into A values(100643085   ,'2021-3-27');
 insert into A values(100645028   ,'2021-3-27');
 
 create table B (ID int, id_update_dt date);
 insert into B values(100067842   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100100227   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100319616   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100344419   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100464912   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100570028   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100608364   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100624076   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100643085   ,'2021-3-25');
 insert into B values(100645028   ,'2021-3-25');
```

Query:

```
 select
 A.ID, A.id_update_dt
 from
 A inner join B
   on A.ID = B.ID
 and A.id_update_dt> B.id_update_dt
```

Output:

| ID | id_update_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 100067842 | 2021-03-27 |
| 100100227 | 2021-03-27 |
| 100344419 | 2021-03-27 |
| 100464912 | 2021-03-27 |
| 100608364 | 2021-03-27 |
| 100643085 | 2021-03-27 |
| 100645028 | 2021-03-27 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5f108f76120acc8c359ff506aed1bb2)*

Comment: Thanks @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur for your response. However, I modified the query and no rows returned.

Comment: You are welcome. I have tried the query on your provided sample data and it's working.